# Dual brush function in texture painting?

Tags: texture-painting, customization

I am wanting to mimic the 'dual brush' function from brush settings in Photoshop, with texture painting in Blender. Essentially, what I am after is the ability to have either two brush textures that I can blend between  in a single stroke, based on pen pressure. Or two whole brushes i can blend between based on pen pressure. Does anyone know if something like this exists?

Fyi, I am trying to recreate Dave Grecko's DG_Main brush from this link: https://youtu.be/-oPp6NE4WL8?t=50

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Answer is below, thanks! There is a function I can work with to get close enough to what I am after :)
[image]

Comment: Are you looking for two different textures, or a single texture across multiple colors based on pressure? A simple set up is to use the brush mask texture to rake and random but set to pressure, as well as using a color gradient with two color stops to blend between them.

Comment: Na colors are fine, I am wanting to use two separate textures for the brush, and blend between them in a single stroke...hope that makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: No, there isn't a way to switch between two textures based on pressure in the brush itself. The example given shows how to switch between two colors with the same mask texture used, which is closer to what the linked video showed at the time mark given. IF you simply want to mix two textures, one can be set to the brush texture and one to the brush texture mask, and use separate mapping.

If the gradient is what you are looking for, here is a quick example of the settings to use with a 'Texture Mask' brush and using a two stop gradient set to pressure.[image]

Here I set an image of a square to the main brush texture calculate alpha, rake and use stucco on brush mask set to 'cutoff' for pressure. I hope this one maybe helps. Square has to be mapped to like 1.60 instead of 1 so that there is visibility of the edges inside the brush sphere.[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah the fact that the video is about blending colors is a bit misleading, my bad. The function of the brush that I am after is how it blends between the scattered-type texture, and then as more pressure is applied, it forms into a solid square type texture. 
https://youtu.be/-oPp6NE4WL8?t=86

The brush he is showing is using the 'dual brush' function in photoshop, which seems to be able to blend between two different brushes - in this case, the scattered-type brush and the solid square type brush. Was hoping there'd be a way to wrangle it in blender! Perhaps not

Comment: Yeah, if we could set up a square brush on the main texture, and then use the noise texture on the texture brush mask, then you could set it to cutoff on the mask to ease up and allow the solid for you.

Comment: Tried to make a sample file for you https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FStnwKd9MEOfiyY2shz4nU1f0St_io-8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Great idea man! Thanks heaps I'll give it a go

Comment: Yeah I can work with that function to get near enough to what I am after. Thanks heaps! Love this community.